# R\Q a subset of Z?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

I have to determine if the following statement is true or false:
$\mathbb{R} \setminus\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Z}$, where $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are the Real numbers, Rational numbers, and integers respectively.
I got stuck. Your suggestions on how to proceed will be greatly appreciated.
This is as much as I got.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Try to prove it false with a counterexample

Comment: What set is $\sqrt{2}$ in?

Comment: What an embarrassing mistake. I have already corrected it. Thank you

Comment: This is the kind of question where it's much better to think about what the sets $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ actually are, rather than formal definitions of set containment, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dropped a "not" symbol from $x \in Q$ in your third line to $y \in Q$ in your fourth line.

But, on the other hand, it does help to simply forget the logic for a moment and ask yourself "What does the statement "$R \setminus Q \subset Z$ actually say?" On the left hand side of the $\subset$ symbol is $R \setminus Q$, which is the set of reals that are not rational, which is the set of irrational numbers. On the right hand side is the set of integers. So, this sentence is saying "every irrational number is an integer".

Perhaps you can take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

The statement is obviously false. In fact, $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are disjoint, because no irrational number could ever be an integer.